# Adding multiple validations to a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, validation

I'm adding some validations to a form in excel.

The rule is displayed when the cell is selected, and the cell must highlight red when it doesn't match the criteria.

This is usually fine except I need to add multiple validations to one cell and I can't get it to work.

Example: cell `D25` must equal the totals of `E25:H25` AND `D27:D31`. Neither `OR` or `AND` seem to work, and it only seems to ever work when it adds the sums of both criteria together.

```
=OR(D25<>SUM(D27:D31), D25<>SUM(E25:H25))

=AND(D25<>SUM(D27:D31), D25<>SUM(E25:H25))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can use this Formula:*

`=OR(D7=SUM(D1:D5),D7=SUM(F1:H1))`

[image]

**N.B.**

- When `D7` is neither equals to the `SUM` of `D1:D5` nor equals to `SUM` of `F1:H1`.
- Cell `D9` has same formula to justify the Formula I've used for Validation.
- Later on you may hid Cell `D9` for neatness.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @david,, keep asking ☺